# Terminal and some application ignores xmodmap

Tags: keyboard

I did config on ~/.Xmodmap

```
clear mod1
keycode 108 = o O
add mod1 = Alt_R
```

and run

```
xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
```

or

```
xmodmap -e 'keycode  108 = o O'
```

It's works in firefox or file manager but on terminal, gedit and others Application its not working.

I really need to map my "o" letter is broken and would like use ALT Right.

Is there's any other solutions using `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/` or `/usr/lib/udev/hwdb.d/60-keyboard.hwdb`

Comment: try `xmodmap -e 'keysym ISO_Level3_Shift = o O'`. (`xev` is really usefull for finding out how keys are called)

Comment: using ```keysym ISO_Level3_Shift = o O``` not working